# Scrapy dynamic creation of objects + json export

Tags: python, json, scrapy

I created a new spider to crawl a website. 
This crawler get each video game of liste on website and create an object for it :

```
class gameInfos(Item):
    title = Field()
    desc = Field()
    kind = Field()
```

for each game, the website contains a variable list of resellers. I get each reseller in object :

```
class buyInfos(Item):
    name = Field()
    address = Field()
    price = Field()
```

Now, my problem :

I want put `buyInfos` object(s) inside `gameInfos` object and that my json file looks :

```
[
   {
    "title": "BF3",
    "desc": "a beautiful game",
    "kind" : "FPS",
    "buy" : 
           [
              {name : "cdiscount", "address" : "example", "price" : "45 €"},
              {name : "amazon", "address" : "example amazon", "price" : "40 €"},
               //... other resellers
           ]
   },
   {
    "title": "COD 42",
    "desc": "a game",
    "kind" : "FPS",
    "buy" :
   }, 
   //... other games
]
```

So I tried to create an object in my main object. It works but finally, I have only one object to fill, whereas I want create some objects inside my main object.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was simple. Create an object as:

```
class GameInfo(Item):
    title = Field()
    desc = Field()
    kind = Field()
    listeBuys = Field()
```

Then, in your spider, instances GameInfo:

```
gameInfo = GameInfo()
```

Then, instances python list for desired field:

```
gameInfo['listeBuys'] = []
```

Finally, add as you want:

```
gameInfo['listeBuys'].append(asyouwant)
```

Thanks dm03514 for his help !

Answer (score 1):

Scrapy [`Field`](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/item.py#L18) class is a subclass of `dict`.  If you want to make one of the fields able to contain a list of `Item`s I believe you could create a List field.

```
class ListField(list):
  pass

class GameInfo(Item):
    title = Field()
    desc = Field()
    kind = Field()
    buys = ListField()
```

Now in your spider you can create the `gameInfos` and it will be able to contain all the relevant `buyInfos`

```
game_info = GameInfo()
# create your buy info and append to game info
game_info['buys'].append(new_buy_info)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but I have a probleme.

I created "ListField" like you and I added a field "infos = ListField()" in my main object.
<br><br>
Then, in my spider : I create my main object (game_info = GameInfo()) and my subObject.<br>
After, I try :<br> game_info.append(new_buy_info) <br>but an error came => <br>
<br>
`game_info.append(subObject)
          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/item.py", line 64, in __getattr__
            raise AttributeError(name)
        exceptions.AttributeError: append`

Comment: @user2240632 sorry fixed example

Comment: I got an error : `File "/root/mycrawler/mycrawler/spiders/jiwire.py", line 107, in parse_hotspot
            game_info["buys"].append("test")
          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/item.py", line 49, in __getitem__
            return self._values[key]
        exceptions.KeyError: 'buys'`

Comment: @user2240632 c'mon you have to adapt the concept in the answer to your actual code.  `buys` refers to whatever key you assign the `ListField` to.  In your other post you said it was `info`

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand. I have to add field inside my list object ? (as class ListField(list): field = subObject())